# PHPExcel save and retrieve MySql

Tags: php, mysql, blob, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to generate a spreadsheet.

If I generate and download at the same time, everything is fine.

But when I save to a MediumBlob in my MySQL and *then* download it, MSExcel says it is not ok.

I am using the same headers in both situations.

Gera is the function that generates the file:

```
$agora=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$relatorio_rh_xls=$dbHandle->real_escape_string(RelatorioBaseRH::Gera($ciclo,$dbHandle));

$qry="insert into tb_relatorio_rh (id_avaliacao_ciclo,relatorio_base_RH_xls,inicio_vigencia,fim_vigencia) values ( $ciclo,'".$relatorio_rh_xls."','".$agora."',null)";

$result4=$dbHandle->query($qry);
```

And then to retrieve it:

```
$query = "SELECT $nomeRelatorio, OCTET_LENGTH($nomeRelatorio) as tamanho " .
                 "FROM tb_relatorio_rh WHERE id_avaliacao_ciclo = '$id_avaliacao_ciclo' and fim_vigencia is null order by inicio_vigencia desc";
$resultadoConsulta= $dbHandle->query($query);

$qtdeLinhas=$resultadoConsulta->num_rows;
        if ($qtdeLinhas>0) {
            $fetBuscaRelatorio = $resultadoConsulta->fetch_assoc();
            $relatorio=$fetBuscaRelatorio[$nomeRelatorio];
            $size=$fetBuscaRelatorio['tamanho'];


            $type= substr($nomeRelatorio, -3, 3);

            if ($type == "xls"){ $type="xlsx";}

            $nomeAvaliado= str_replace(' ','_',$nomeAvaliado);

            $nomeDownload=substr($nomeRelatorio, 0, strlen($nomeRelatorio)-4) .'_' . $nomeAvaliado .'.'. $type;

            header("Content-Length: $size");
            header("Content-Type: $type");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nomeDownload");

            print $relatorio;
}
```

Comment: The Excel error code is 101590

Comment: What do you mean by "is not ok"? What's the specific error?

Comment: save the file, open with text editor, check top and bottom for html or php errors

Comment: @AaronBrager the error code is 101590.

Comment: @Dagon no errors. There is just some few readable texts like [Content_Types].xml­”MNÃ0

Comment: Make absolutely certain that there is no leading or trailing whitespace or BOM header when the file is downloaded

Comment: @MarkBaker nothing in download. in upload i have $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
      ob_start();
      $objWriter->save('php://output');
      $excelOutput = ob_get_clean();
  
      return ($excelOutput);

Comment: @MarkBaker you are correct. I had blank lines in a php class file I was including with include_once. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with another php file I was including with include_once(anotherfile.php).

That anotherfile.php had blank lines after ?> closing tag.